# Im having trouble editing an object in OOP in my project

Tags: python, oop

Basically im doing a project in `python` as part of my full stack course, and i have ran into wall.
My project is a parking lot system, which gets you a ticket with your cars number, unique code, time entered. At the exit you will have to write the unique code and it will calculate the cost for the parked time. I created a class named `Key` which creates the object it self with the exit time as `None`, but my trouble begins by trying to update the `self.exit` which doesn't work out for me using the the [function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTRvl.png) `exit_time`. Every time a car enters the data is written to a file using `pickle`, i tried using a list to be able to edit the object but something isn't working out for me.
Also I tried many varieties by calling the function or what happens in the function it self.

## THIS IS MY MAIN

```
list_of_cars = []
while True:
    startmessage() # prints message 
    choice() # prints message 
    action = input("\nYour choice: ")
    if action == "1":
        choice_one() # prints message 
        car_number = input(" here: ")
        new_client = Key(car_number)
        list_of_cars.append(new_client)
        writing_file(list_of_cars)
        reading_file()
    if action == "2":
        choice_two() # prints message 
        exit_key = input(" here: ")
        Key(exit_key).exit_time(exit_key)
```

## READ AND WRITE

```
def reading_file():
    with open("parking.data", "rb") as readfile:
        list_of_cars = pickle.load(readfile)
        print("testing", [str(x) for x in list_of_cars])
        readfile.close()
        return list_of_cars


def writing_file(list_of_cars):
    with open("parking.data", "wb") as myfile:
        pickle.dump(list_of_cars, myfile)
        myfile.close()
        return list_of_cars
```

## THE CLASS

```
import random
import pickle
import datetime as dt


class Key:

    def __init__(self, car_number):
        self.car_number = car_number
        self.key = self.generate()
        self.enter = self.enter_time()
        self.exit = None
        """
        creates the key it self and while creating it checks if it already exists so that there will be no duplicates
        """

    def generate(self):
        key = ""
        chunk = ""
        alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRZTUVWXYZ1234567890"
        while True:
            while len(key) < 8:
                char = random.choice(alphabet)
                key += char
                chunk += char
                if len(chunk) == 3:
                    key += "-"
                    chunk = ""
            key = key[:-1]
            with open("parking.data", "rb") as readfile:
                new_list = pickle.load(readfile)
                if key in new_list:
                    key = ""
                else:
                    return key

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.car_number},{self.key}," \
               f"{self.enter},{self.exit}"

    def enter_time(self):
        start = str(dt.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
        return start

    def exit_time(self, exit_key):
        from read_and_write import reading_file
        list_of_cars = reading_file()
        if exit_key in list_of_cars:
            self.exit = str(dt.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
            print("IT WORKED!!!")
        print("got to the function :/")
```

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", please state what the expected and actual behaviors are.

Comment: i would like to change the self.exit upon exiting to the current time so I would be able to calculate the cost, but after calling the function nothing changes.
This is the list that I get = ['5412,OM7-XVX,21:09:42,None', '543412,P4D-YQZ,21:09:50,None', '4123,F1Q-R6F,21:09:53,None']

Comment: I think the problem is about the returns of your `reading_file` and `writing_file` functions. After you close the files, you can return the function with 4 spaces as indention, aligned to `with`s.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify it. Make sure that your code is a [mcve]. I have the feeling that this has nothing to do with OOP, btw. In any case, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt @Solomon Ucko It is the `if` statement in `exit_time` causing issues

Answer (score 1):

your conditional is:

```
if exit_key in list_of_cars:
```

`exit_key` is `OM7-XVX`

`list_of_cars` is `['5412,OM7-XVX,21:09:42,None1',...]`

So...

```
'OM7-XVX' in ['5412,OM7-XVX,21:09:42,None1'] -> False
'OM7-XVX' in ['5412,OM7-XVX,21:09:42,None1'][0] -> True
```

Therefore replace the conditional with

```
if any(exit_key in v for v in list_of_cars):
```

Comment: in my "main.py" I changed the line which calls the function from: "Key.exit_time(exit_key)" because it says - "TypeError: Key.exit_time() missing 1 required positional argument: 'exit_key'"

changed to Key(exit_key).exit_time(exit_key) and I get - 

TypeError: argument of type 'Key' is not iterable